# DDD entity VS service

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have a class called `TicketIssue`, it has the properties:

- idPrimary
- idGroup
- idModel
- weight
- briefDescription

The logic behind calculating weight is quite complicated and requires querying other entities. Do I:

1. Inject those other entities into this one (yuck)
2. Query a repository for those entities in this entity (not much better than injection?)
3. Implement a service which calculates the weight and then sets it on the entity before being persisted
4. Implement an event

To add to this question, this entity also requires some robust logic when a ticket is created... notifying intended parties via email etc.

Implementing an `addNew()` in this entity doesn't feel right, should I have a service (or factory?) that persists the entity and fires off emails, and kick starts the workflow???

Comment: A few clarifications: What do you mean by injecting entities, are the entities managed by some DI framework ? How is the weight calculation dependent on other entities, do it need some processing done by them, or does it just depend on some values from these entities ? When is the weight value calculated during creation, or on some other event ?

Comment: Since my answer has a lot of questions I'll ask them here. Does `TicketIssue` have relations with other entities? Why don't `TicketIssue` know about them? When do you need to calculate weight (during creation, during retrieving entity from DB, during update)?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can use an event, on creating the record.
On the event, you can call a service to calculate weight.

So the event will act as a trigger, that will do a bunch of automatic things.
Inside the event (or "code-trigger"), you can use a service to calculate or process several things.

Thank you,